# Using link_to with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the following code to display the name of the contact and link to their message.

```
<%= link_to message.contact.try(:name), message_path(message) %>
```

When a contact is deleted from the list, I would like to show a placeholder like "Contact deleted" and link to the message instead of just showing the URL. I tried `link_to_if`, but it didn't offer the expected output. Is there an effective solution for this?

Comment: You can use a ternary operator in the first parameter to change the text of the link, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @PaulRichter yes, I tried that, but couldn't get the syntax quiet right when using link_to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `link_to_if` if the name of the link is the same. You can also use it with a workaround.

```
<%= link_to_if message.contact, message.contact ? message.contact.name : "Contact deleted", message_path(message) %>
```

However, I think the cleanest approach is an `if`.

```
<% if message.contact %>
  <%= link_to message.contact.name, message_path(message) %>
<% else %>
  Contact deleted
<% end %>
```

Comment: I get undefined method `contact?'error when using the second suggestion.

Comment: I assumed it was part of the association. Simply check the presence then.